# Is there a better way to use Pandas to find garbage data?

Tags: python, pandas, validation

I have a set of data that I'm trying to locate discrepancies in. For example if Column A has a value of 'Approved' then Column B should have a date, otherwise it should have a value of 'NA'. I'm trying to identify all the lines that violate that logic.

Right now I'm importing as a pandas dataframe, moving the column names to a list and indexing them to identify the correct column position. Then I'm iterating through each row and using .iloc to save the values at each position to variables. After that I apply my logic checks to the variables, and append any mismatches to a list for later cleanup and export to excel. It's working fine, but I feel like it can be done more efficiently.

Is there a better way for me to do this? Everything I've seen in terms of using pandas for validation is about checking that the data is in the appropriate format, but I haven't found anything about comparing column values on a row by row basis.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Showing your code is generally necessary in addition to describing it linguistically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can test your logic without iteration (faster) using the `pandas.DataFrame` built-in queries:

```
df['check'] = (df['columnA'] == 'Approved') & (df['columnB'].dtype == 'type')
```

The upper code builds a new column containing the result of the logic operations.

Comment: In this case, the logic operators check for the first column to have the value approved and the second having the value type 'type'. The code only gives True for those rows that satisfy both conditions.

Comment: Thanks! I will definitely try this out.